# Retrieving Affected Object from serialized data

Tags: javers

Am working on finding the differences between two Json objects and storing the respective Diff in Json format(using Javers), so that can be retrieve later and presented to the user in a meaningful manner. Now, the challenge is, the Affected Object(where the change has happened) is not being serialized during serialization.
I understand that it is not possible to retrieve the domain objects from Diff.
Could see that the "affectedCdo" has been marked as transient not allowing to serialize it.
Any other alternative for doing this?

Thanks,
Ravi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restoring orginal domain objects from persisted snapshots will be possible when we implemen the *shadows* feature in JaVers. We are working on it. https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/133

Comment: Any tentative date for the feature availability?

Comment: April, maybe May

Comment: Shadows look good, but how do get the AffectedObject from the serialized `Diff`? Just comparing objects, no database underneath.

Comment: It's easy to find: Change.getAffectedObject()